# Why products.php is not affecting any changes in product.twig Opencart 3.0?

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I am developing an OpenCart 3.0.0 website. I need to add categories list in every product page. I have added loop to get the category list in product.php and displaying it in products.twig also. But there is no category listed in the product page.

Here is the code for product.php

```
<?php
class ControllerProductProduct extends Controller {
    private $error = array();

    public function index() {
        $this->load->language('product/product');

        $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('common/home')
        );

        $this->load->model('catalog/category');

        if (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
            $path = '';

            $parts = explode('_', (string)$this->request->get['path']);

            $category_id = (int)array_pop($parts);

            foreach ($parts as $path_id) {
                if (!$path) {
                    $path = $path_id;
                } else {
                    $path .= '_' . $path_id;
                }

                $category_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($path_id);

                if ($category_info) {
                    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                        'text' => $category_info['name'],
                        'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $path)
                    );
                }
            }

            // Set the last category breadcrumb
            $category_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($category_id);

            if ($category_info) {
                $url = '';

                if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
                    $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
                }

                if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
                    $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
                }

                if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
                    $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
                }

                if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
                    $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
                }

                $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                    'text' => $category_info['name'],
                    'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . $url)
                );
            }
        }

        $this->load->model('catalog/manufacturer');

        if (isset($this->request->get['manufacturer_id'])) {
            $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                'text' => $this->language->get('text_brand'),
                'href' => $this->url->link('product/manufacturer')
            );

            $url = '';

            if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
                $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
                $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
                $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
                $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
            }

            $manufacturer_info = $this->model_catalog_manufacturer->getManufacturer($this->request->get['manufacturer_id']);

            if ($manufacturer_info) {
                $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                    'text' => $manufacturer_info['name'],
                    'href' => $this->url->link('product/manufacturer/info', 'manufacturer_id=' . $this->request->get['manufacturer_id'] . $url)
                );
            }
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['search']) || isset($this->request->get['tag'])) {
            $url = '';

            if (isset($this->request->get['search'])) {
                $url .= '&search=' . $this->request->get['search'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['tag'])) {
                $url .= '&tag=' . $this->request->get['tag'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['description'])) {
                $url .= '&description=' . $this->request->get['description'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['category_id'])) {
                $url .= '&category_id=' . $this->request->get['category_id'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['sub_category'])) {
                $url .= '&sub_category=' . $this->request->get['sub_category'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
                $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
                $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
                $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
                $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
            }

            $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                'text' => $this->language->get('text_search'),
                'href' => $this->url->link('product/search', $url)
            );
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['product_id'])) {
            $product_id = (int)$this->request->get['product_id'];
        } else {
            $product_id = 0;
        }

        $this->load->model('catalog/product');

//      $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);
        $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);
        $query_categories = $this->model_catalog_product->getCategories($product_id);

        $categories = array();

        foreach ($query_categories as $cat) {
            $ocb_category = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($cat['category_id']);

            $category_info['category_id'] = $ocb_category['category_id'];
            $category_info['name'] = $ocb_category['name'];
            $data['categories'][] = $category_info; 
        }

        if ($product_info) {
            $url = '';

            if (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
                $url .= '&path=' . $this->request->get['path'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['filter'])) {
                $url .= '&filter=' . $this->request->get['filter'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['manufacturer_id'])) {
                $url .= '&manufacturer_id=' . $this->request->get['manufacturer_id'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['search'])) {
                $url .= '&search=' . $this->request->get['search'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['tag'])) {
                $url .= '&tag=' . $this->request->get['tag'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['description'])) {
                $url .= '&description=' . $this->request->get['description'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['category_id'])) {
                $url .= '&category_id=' . $this->request->get['category_id'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['sub_category'])) {
                $url .= '&sub_category=' . $this->request->get['sub_category'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
                $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
                $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
                $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
                $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
            }

            $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                'text' => $product_info['name'],
                'href' => $this->url->link('product/product', $url . '&product_id=' . $this->request->get['product_id'])
            );

            $this->document->setTitle($product_info['meta_title']);
            $this->document->setDescription($product_info['meta_description']);
            $this->document->setKeywords($product_info['meta_keyword']);
            $this->document->addLink($this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $this->request->get['product_id']), 'canonical');
            $this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/magnific/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js');
            $this->document->addStyle('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/magnific/magnific-popup.css');
            $this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/moment/moment.min.js');
            $this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/moment/moment-with-locales.min.js');
            $this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js');
            $this->document->addStyle('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css');

            $data['heading_title'] = $product_info['name'];

            $data['text_minimum'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_minimum'), $product_info['minimum']);
            $data['text_login'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_login'), $this->url->link('account/login', '', true), $this->url->link('account/register', '', true));

            $this->load->model('catalog/review');

            $data['tab_review'] = sprintf($this->language->get('tab_review'), $product_info['reviews']);

            $data['product_id'] = (int)$this->request->get['product_id'];
            $data['manufacturer'] = $product_info['manufacturer'];
            $data['manufacturers'] = $this->url->link('product/manufacturer/info', 'manufacturer_id=' . $product_info['manufacturer_id']);
            $data['model'] = $product_info['model'];
            $data['reward'] = $product_info['reward'];
            $data['points'] = $product_info['points'];
            $data['description'] = html_entity_decode($product_info['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

            if ($product_info['quantity'] <= 0) {
                $data['stock'] = $product_info['stock_status'];
            } elseif ($this->config->get('config_stock_display')) {
                $data['stock'] = $product_info['quantity'];
            } else {
                $data['stock'] = $this->language->get('text_instock');
            }

            $this->load->model('tool/image');

            if ($product_info['image']) {
                $data['popup'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($product_info['image'], $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_popup_width'), $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_popup_height'));
            } else {
                $data['popup'] = '';
            }

            if ($product_info['image']) {
                $data['thumb'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($product_info['image'], $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_thumb_width'), $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_thumb_height'));
            } else {
                $data['thumb'] = '';
            }

            $data['images'] = array();

            $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductImages($this->request->get['product_id']);

            foreach ($results as $result) {
                $data['images'][] = array(
                    'popup' => $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_popup_width'), $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_popup_height')),
                    'thumb' => $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_additional_width'), $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_additional_height'))
                );
            }

            if ($this->customer->isLogged() || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
                $data['price'] = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_info['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
            } else {
                $data['price'] = false;
            }

            if ((float)$product_info['special']) {
                $data['special'] = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_info['special'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
            } else {
                $data['special'] = false;
            }

            if ($this->config->get('config_tax')) {
                $data['tax'] = $this->currency->format((float)$product_info['special'] ? $product_info['special'] : $product_info['price'], $this->session->data['currency']);
            } else {
                $data['tax'] = false;
            }

            $discounts = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductDiscounts($this->request->get['product_id']);

            $data['discounts'] = array();

            foreach ($discounts as $discount) {
                $data['discounts'][] = array(
                    'quantity' => $discount['quantity'],
                    'price'    => $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($discount['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency'])
                );
            }

            $data['options'] = array();

            foreach ($this->model_catalog_product->getProductOptions($this->request->get['product_id']) as $option) {
                $product_option_value_data = array();

                foreach ($option['product_option_value'] as $option_value) {
                    if (!$option_value['subtract'] || ($option_value['quantity'] > 0)) {
                        if ((($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) && (float)$option_value['price']) {
                            $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($option_value['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax') ? 'P' : false), $this->session->data['currency']);
                        } else {
                            $price = false;
                        }

                        $product_option_value_data[] = array(
                            'product_option_value_id' => $option_value['product_option_value_id'],
                            'option_value_id'         => $option_value['option_value_id'],
                            'name'                    => $option_value['name'],
                            'image'                   => $this->model_tool_image->resize($option_value['image'], 50, 50),
                            'price'                   => $price,
                            'price_prefix'            => $option_value['price_prefix']
                        );
                    }
                }

                $data['options'][] = array(
                    'product_option_id'    => $option['product_option_id'],
                    'product_option_value' => $product_option_value_data,
                    'option_id'            => $option['option_id'],
                    'name'                 => $option['name'],
                    'type'                 => $option['type'],
                    'value'                => $option['value'],
                    'required'             => $option['required']
                );
            }

            if ($product_info['minimum']) {
                $data['minimum'] = $product_info['minimum'];
            } else {
                $data['minimum'] = 1;
            }

            $data['review_status'] = $this->config->get('config_review_status');

            if ($this->config->get('config_review_guest') || $this->customer->isLogged()) {
                $data['review_guest'] = true;
            } else {
                $data['review_guest'] = false;
            }

            if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
                $data['customer_name'] = $this->customer->getFirstName() . '&nbsp;' . $this->customer->getLastName();
            } else {
                $data['customer_name'] = '';
            }

            $data['reviews'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_reviews'), (int)$product_info['reviews']);
            $data['rating'] = (int)$product_info['rating'];

            // Captcha
            if ($this->config->get('captcha_' . $this->config->get('config_captcha') . '_status') && in_array('review', (array)$this->config->get('config_captcha_page'))) {
                $data['captcha'] = $this->load->controller('extension/captcha/' . $this->config->get('config_captcha'));
            } else {
                $data['captcha'] = '';
            }

            $data['share'] = $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . (int)$this->request->get['product_id']);

            $data['attribute_groups'] = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductAttributes($this->request->get['product_id']);

            $data['products'] = array();

            $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductRelated($this->request->get['product_id']);

            foreach ($results as $result) {
                if ($result['image']) {
                    $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_related_width'), $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_related_height'));
                } else {
                    $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize('placeholder.png', $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_related_width'), $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_related_height'));
                }

                if ($this->customer->isLogged() || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
                    $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['price'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
                } else {
                    $price = false;
                }

                if ((float)$result['special']) {
                    $special = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['special'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
                } else {
                    $special = false;
                }

                if ($this->config->get('config_tax')) {
                    $tax = $this->currency->format((float)$result['special'] ? $result['special'] : $result['price'], $this->session->data['currency']);
                } else {
                    $tax = false;
                }

                if ($this->config->get('config_review_status')) {
                    $rating = (int)$result['rating'];
                } else {
                    $rating = false;
                }

                $data['products'][] = array(
                    'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
                    'thumb'       => $image,
                    'name'        => $result['name'],
                    'description' => utf8_substr(trim(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'))), 0, $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_description_length')) . '..',
                    'price'       => $price,
                    'special'     => $special,
                    'tax'         => $tax,
                    'minimum'     => $result['minimum'] > 0 ? $result['minimum'] : 1,
                    'rating'      => $rating,
                    'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id'])
                );
            }

            $data['tags'] = array();

            if ($product_info['tag']) {
                $tags = explode(',', $product_info['tag']);

                foreach ($tags as $tag) {
                    $data['tags'][] = array(
                        'tag'  => trim($tag),
                        'href' => $this->url->link('product/search', 'tag=' . trim($tag))
                    );
                }
            }

            $data['recurrings'] = $this->model_catalog_product->getProfiles($this->request->get['product_id']);

            $this->model_catalog_product->updateViewed($this->request->get['product_id']);
            
            $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
            $data['column_right'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_right');
            $data['content_top'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_top');
            $data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_bottom');
            $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
            $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');

            $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('product/product', $data));
        } else {
            $url = '';

            if (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
                $url .= '&path=' . $this->request->get['path'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['filter'])) {
                $url .= '&filter=' . $this->request->get['filter'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['manufacturer_id'])) {
                $url .= '&manufacturer_id=' . $this->request->get['manufacturer_id'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['search'])) {
                $url .= '&search=' . $this->request->get['search'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['tag'])) {
                $url .= '&tag=' . $this->request->get['tag'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['description'])) {
                $url .= '&description=' . $this->request->get['description'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['category_id'])) {
                $url .= '&category_id=' . $this->request->get['category_id'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['sub_category'])) {
                $url .= '&sub_category=' . $this->request->get['sub_category'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
                $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
                $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
                $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
                $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
            }

            $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                'text' => $this->language->get('text_error'),
                'href' => $this->url->link('product/product', $url . '&product_id=' . $product_id)
            );

            $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('text_error'));

            $data['continue'] = $this->url->link('common/home');

            $this->response->addHeader($this->request->server['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 404 Not Found');

            $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
            $data['column_right'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_right');
            $data['content_top'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_top');
            $data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_bottom');
            $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
            $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');

            $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('error/not_found', $data));
        }
    }

    public function review() {
        $this->load->language('product/product');

        $this->load->model('catalog/review');

        if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
            $page = $this->request->get['page'];
        } else {
            $page = 1;
        }

        $data['reviews'] = array();

        $review_total = $this->model_catalog_review->getTotalReviewsByProductId($this->request->get['product_id']);

        $results = $this->model_catalog_review->getReviewsByProductId($this->request->get['product_id'], ($page - 1) * 5, 5);

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            $data['reviews'][] = array(
                'author'     => $result['author'],
                'text'       => nl2br($result['text']),
                'rating'     => (int)$result['rating'],
                'date_added' => date($this->language->get('date_format_short'), strtotime($result['date_added']))
            );
        }

        $pagination = new Pagination();
        $pagination->total = $review_total;
        $pagination->page = $page;
        $pagination->limit = 5;
        $pagination->url = $this->url->link('product/product/review', 'product_id=' . $this->request->get['product_id'] . '&page={page}');

        $data['pagination'] = $pagination->render();

        $data['results'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_pagination'), ($review_total) ? (($page - 1) * 5) + 1 : 0, ((($page - 1) * 5) > ($review_total - 5)) ? $review_total : ((($page - 1) * 5) + 5), $review_total, ceil($review_total / 5));

        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('product/review', $data));
    }

    public function write() {
        $this->load->language('product/product');

        $json = array();

        if ($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
            if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['name']) < 3) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['name']) > 25)) {
                $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_name');
            }

            if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['text']) < 25) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['text']) > 1000)) {
                $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_text');
            }

            if (empty($this->request->post['rating']) || $this->request->post['rating'] < 0 || $this->request->post['rating'] > 5) {
                $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_rating');
            }

            // Captcha
            if ($this->config->get('captcha_' . $this->config->get('config_captcha') . '_status') && in_array('review', (array)$this->config->get('config_captcha_page'))) {
                $captcha = $this->load->controller('extension/captcha/' . $this->config->get('config_captcha') . '/validate');

                if ($captcha) {
                    $json['error'] = $captcha;
                }
            }

            if (!isset($json['error'])) {
                $this->load->model('catalog/review');

                $this->model_catalog_review->addReview($this->request->get['product_id'], $this->request->post);

                $json['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');
            }
        }

        $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
        $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
    }

    public function getRecurringDescription() {
        $this->load->language('product/product');
        $this->load->model('catalog/product');

        if (isset($this->request->post['product_id'])) {
            $product_id = $this->request->post['product_id'];
        } else {
            $product_id = 0;
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['recurring_id'])) {
            $recurring_id = $this->request->post['recurring_id'];
        } else {
            $recurring_id = 0;
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['quantity'])) {
            $quantity = $this->request->post['quantity'];
        } else {
            $quantity = 1;
        }

        $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);
        $query_categories = $this->model_catalog_product->getCategories($product_id);

        $categories = array();

        foreach ($query_categories as $cat) {
            $ocb_category = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($cat['category_id']);

            $category_info['category_id'] = $ocb_category['category_id'];
            $category_info['name'] = $ocb_category['name'];
            $data['categories'][] = $category_info; 
        }

        $recurring_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProfile($product_id, $recurring_id);

        $json = array();

        if ($product_info && $recurring_info) {
            if (!$json) {
                $frequencies = array(
                    'day'        => $this->language->get('text_day'),
                    'week'       => $this->language->get('text_week'),
                    'semi_month' => $this->language->get('text_semi_month'),
                    'month'      => $this->language->get('text_month'),
                    'year'       => $this->language->get('text_year'),
                );

                if ($recurring_info['trial_status'] == 1) {
                    $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($recurring_info['trial_price'] * $quantity, $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
                    $trial_text = sprintf($this->language->get('text_trial_description'), $price, $recurring_info['trial_cycle'], $frequencies[$recurring_info['trial_frequency']], $recurring_info['trial_duration']) . ' ';
                } else {
                    $trial_text = '';
                }

                $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($recurring_info['price'] * $quantity, $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);

                if ($recurring_info['duration']) {
                    $text = $trial_text . sprintf($this->language->get('text_payment_description'), $price, $recurring_info['cycle'], $frequencies[$recurring_info['frequency']], $recurring_info['duration']);
                } else {
                    $text = $trial_text . sprintf($this->language->get('text_payment_cancel'), $price, $recurring_info['cycle'], $frequencies[$recurring_info['frequency']], $recurring_info['duration']);
                }

                $json['success'] = $text;
            }
        }

        $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
        $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
    }
}
```

Here is my product.twig code:

```
{% if (categories) %} 
    {% for category in categories %} 
        {% if category.category_id %} 
           <a>{{category.name}}:{{category.category_id}}<a><br>
        {% endif %} 
    {% endfor %} 
{% endif %}
```

Help me to do this. I have tried to edit codes in the product.php but it is not working at all. Theme editor is not displaying my theme, so I do manual code edit at files.

Comment: Have you tried clearing cache in the backend?

Comment: I have cleared cache folder but no result. But I have tried to delete and change storage directory through admin. Now it is working. I don't know why?

Comment: That's strange, perhaps you have an OCMOD installed that modifies the product page. In that case, you might want to Refresh the modification cache as well.